# How to read from URL line-wise?

Tags: perl

I'm looking for the "moral equivalent" of the (fictitious) `openremote` below:

```
my $handle = openremote( 'http://some.domain.org/huge.tsv' ) or die $!;
while ( <$handle> ) {
    chomp;
    # etc.
    # do stuff with $_
}
close $handle;
```

IOW, I'm looking for a way to open a read handle to a remote file so that I can read from it *line-by-line*.  (Typically this file will be larger than I want to read entirely into memory.  This means that solutions based on stuffing the value returned by `LWP::Simple::get` (for example) into an `IO::String` are not suitable.)

I'm sure this is really basic stuff, but I have not been able to find it after a lot of searching.

Comment: @kjo Maybe try IO::Socket. Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9227603/perl-creating-a-socket

Comment: So you don't want to fetch the file and read from it you want to read from it over the network??   Is this a job for something like [`POE`](http://poe.perl.org/) or am I misreading your question?

Comment: If one of the answers worked or was suitable please click to accept it. It makes the site useful for people who only search for answered questions. Cheers.

Comment: @Borodin that's not relevant to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a "solution" much like the other responses but it cheats a bit by using  [`IO::All`](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/IO-All/lib/IO/All.pod)

```
use IO::All ;
my $http_io = io->http("http://some.domain.org/huge.tsv");

while (my $line = $http_io->getline || $http_io->getline) {
   print $line;
}
```

After you have an object with `io->http` you can use `IO` methods to look at it (like `getline()` etc.).

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use LWP::UserAgent's parameter :content_file => $filename to save the big file to disk directly, without filling the memory with it, and then you can read that file in your program.

```
$ua->get( $url, ':content_file' => $filename );
```

Or you can use the parameter :content_cb => \&callback and in the callback subroutine you can process the data chunk by chunk as it is downloaded. This is probably the way you need.

```
$ua->get( $url, ':content_cb' => \&callback );

sub callback {
    my ( $chunk, $response, $protocol ) = @_;
    #Do whatever you like with $chunk
}
```

Read (a little) more about this with perldoc LWP::UserAgent.

Answer (score 0):

Use LWP::Simple coupled with IO::String like so:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use LWP::Simple;
use IO::String;

my $handle = IO::String->new(get("http://stackoverflow.com"));
while (defined (my $line = <$handle>)) {
  print $line;
}
close $handle;
```

Hope it works for you.

Paul

Comment: Thanks, but this solution requires reading the entire content of the URL into memory, something I specifically said I did not want to do.  (I've edited my post to make this point more explicit.)